# Positive Operators: Definition?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

**Definitions**

Given an operator algebra $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ with $1\in\mathcal{A}$

Consider selfadjoint operators $A=A^*\in\mathcal{A}$.

Define positive elements by:
$$A\geq0:\iff\sigma(A)\geq0$$
and positive operators by:
$$A\geq0:\iff\mathcal{W}(A)\geq0$$

**Problem**

> Do the numerical range and spectrum coincide:
>   $$A=A^*:\quad\langle\sigma(A)\rangle=\overline{\mathcal{W}(A)}$$

**Attempt**

For bounded operators one has at least:
$$\|A\|<\infty:\quad\sigma(A)\subseteq\overline{\mathcal{W}(A)}$$
So any positive operator is a positive element; but what about the converse?

Comment: I seem to remember that the numerical range and the spectrum have the same convex hull.  Is that right?  If so, then one is positive iff the other is.

Comment: Unfortunately they don't as the example matrix shows. Also for self adjoint unbounded operators this is wrong in general if the spectrum is empty. But maybe there is still some hope for self adjoint *and* bounded operators...

Comment: When you're first starting with a $C^{\star}$ algebra, before knowing that such an algebra can be viewed as part of $\mathscr{B}(H)$, a definition of positivity for selfadjoint operators is possible, but one involving numerical range is not.

Comment: Did you mean "[...] a definition of positivity for selfadjoint operators *'involving spectrum'* is possible, [...]"?? I just remembered right now that a definition involving numerical range is always possible too where the role of normalized vectors is taken by states (positive linear functionals $\omega\in E(\mathcal{A})$).

Comment: It $T$ is a normal bounded operator on a Hilbert space, then $\overline{W(T)} = $ the closed convex hull of $\sigma(T)$, so if $\sigma(T) \subset \mathbb{R}^+$, then $W(T) \subset \mathbb{R}^+$. So the two definitions are equivalent for bounded ops - not sure what happens for unbounded ops.

Comment: Oh thats nice - do you have some reference for further reading on that? Hmm so for unbounded ones the question still open...

Comment: States aren't part of the definition of a $C^{\star}$ algebra. So you can't use numerical range to define positive in that sense, until well after you've needed to be working with such concepts.

Comment: Right ^^ I mixed it up in my head: States require a definition of positivity first.

Comment: Every $C^*$ algebra is an operator algebra on a Hilbert Space.  There are many other definitions too.  Like being the square of a self adjoint element.  Being of the form $a^*a$... I've used all of these definitions at one point or another, although I was only into operator algebras for about half a year before I discovered that was not the field in which I wanted to do my PhD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For unbounded normal operators one has:
$$NN^*=N^*N:\quad\langle\sigma(N)\rangle=\overline{\mathcal{W}(N)}$$
*(See summary on: [Spectrum vs. Numerical Range](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1084146/79762))*

So the notions of positivity agree!