# Summary: Spectrum vs. Numerical Range

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

*This thread is only Q&A!*

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider operators:
$$T:\mathcal{D}(T)\to\mathcal{H}$$

Denote for shorthand:
$$\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}:\quad\langle\Omega\rangle:=\operatorname{conv}(\Omega)$$

Then one has:
$$\langle\sigma(T)\rangle=\overline{\mathcal{W}(T)}$$

Does this hold true?

Comment: When it comes to matters like this, it doesn't matter whether or not someone is a moderator. A moderator has some degree of power, but he should only exercise it to enforce the rules established by the community. I don't intend to say that you shouldn't answer your own question (the option is included in the interface for a reason), just that those links are not really relevant.

Comment: @tomasz: I know but it just seems that some people don't think about it before downvoting or voting to close. I got the impression that explicitely mentioning it prevents people from doing something to overhasty. But yes it even looks so ugly. :(

Comment: @tomasz: But good point: I replaced moderator with community.

Comment: In that case, I think it would be better suited for a comment (because that is what it actually is, and it prevents it from distracting from the actual content).

Comment: Putting in comments seemed not to help.

Comment: @tomasz: Ok you know what let me check for the next few days how much I myself keep attention on the comments of question from other people. Then I will rethink my strategy! ;)

Comment: You have rangle, but not langle surrounding $\sigma(T)$. And, what does this notation mean?

Comment: @T.A.E.: Thanks. :) Here, the convex hull.

Comment: @tomasz: Would you mind deleting our discussion about the formatting issues?

Comment: I would put the definition in the statement of the problem because I don't think there's any really standard notation for convex hull.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Done! ;)

Comment: The way you are posting these questions makes it seem that you are writing a public diary. Wouldn't it be appropriate to make the questions and answers community wiki in order to remove the personal aspect?

Comment: @user161825: How does it work? Actually that is a good idea as it might solve alot of issues about complaints. :)

Comment: @Freeze_S It seems you need to flag your question and ask for a moderator to turn it into a community wiki question. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Comment: @user161825: Hmm, I flew over the aim of cw and this doesn't seem to fit for cw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bounded Operators**

For bounded operators:
$$A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad\langle\sigma(A)\rangle=\overline{\mathcal{W}(A)}\subseteq\mathbb{C}$$

For nilpotent operators:
$$N^{K+1}=0:\quad\langle\sigma(N)\rangle=(0)\subseteq\overline{\mathcal{W}(N)}$$

As standard example:
$$\left\langle\sigma\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle=(0)\subsetneq\frac12\mathbb{D}=\overline{\mathcal{W}\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}}$$

But inclusion always holds!

**Unbounded Operators**

For normal operators:
$$N^*N=NN^*:\quad\langle\sigma(N)\rangle=\overline{\mathcal{W}(N)}\subseteq\mathbb{C}$$

For symmetric operators:
$$S\subseteq\overline{S}\subsetneq S^*:\quad\langle\sigma(S)\rangle\nsubseteq\mathbb{R}\quad\overline{\mathcal{W}(S)}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$$

For unclosed operators:
$$T\subsetneq\overline{T}=T^{**}:\quad\langle\sigma(T)\rangle=\mathbb{C}\supseteq\overline{\mathcal{W}(T)}$$

It may happen even:*
$$S=\overline{S}\subsetneq S^*:\quad\langle\sigma(S)\rangle=\mathbb{C}\supsetneq\mathbb{R}\supseteq\overline{\mathcal{W}(S)}$$

And even worse also:*
$$T=\overline{T}=T^{**}:\quad\langle\sigma(T)\rangle=\varnothing\subsetneq\overline{\mathcal{W}(T)}\subseteq\mathbb{C}$$

So inclusion mostly fails!

**References**

For examples see: [Closed Operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1015171/79762)

For the proof see: [Normal Operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/822319/79762), [Spectral Measures](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1013753/79762)